# OpenGL Integer Textures on OSX (NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M)

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl

I am having problems reading from an unsigned integer texture in my Fragment Shader on OSX 10.9.4 with an GeForce GT 650M.

I am using the OpenGL 3.2 core profile.

`GL_VESION` reports as: `4.1 NVIDIA-8.26.26 310.40.45f01`

`GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION` reports as: `4.10`

Here are the relevant parts of my setup in C++:

```
// ..

GLuint texID;
glGenTextures(1, &texID);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

// data is a void* arg
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, 1024, 2, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data);

// programID is a GLuint arg
GLint const uniID = getUniformID(programID, "my_texture")
glUniform1i(uniID, 0);

// ..
```

Here are the relevant parts from my Fragment Shader code:

```
#version 150 core

// ..

uniform usampler2D my_texture;

// ..

void main()
{
    ivec2 texSize = textureSize(my_texture, 0);

    uint pixelVal = texelFetch(my_texture, ivec2(0, 0), 0).r;

    // ..
}
```

`texSize` is `ivec2(1,1)`, even though I specified a `1024x2` texture.

`pixelVal` is a garbage uint.

I have no gl errors (`glGetError` calls after every OGL API call have been removed from above).

I get the same results when using an integer texture and when using an RGBA unsigned integer texture.

---

When I change the texture to a float texture, things work as expected.

`texSize` is `ivec2(1024,2)`

`pixelVal` is the correct float value

---

When I run the same unsigned integer texture code from above on Windows 7 (ATI Radeon HD 5450 with extensions provided by GLEW), I get the expected results in the Fragment Shader:

`texSize` is `ivec2(1024,2)`

`pixelVal` is the correct uint value

---

Can anyone shed some light on what's going wrong with integer textures on OSX? 
Perhaps there's a bug with my NVIDIA card. Searching has not revealed any reported cases...

Comment: is the line `glUniform1i("my_texture", GL_TEXTURE0);` exactly as in your code? You need to pass the location of the uniform, not the name.

Comment: yes  - apologies, my code uses glGetUniformLocation to get the location from the name (edited)

Comment: Why `#version 150 core` on the shader if you can (and should) use `#version 410`? Fix this and it might work.

Comment: Also, check the shader/program logs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly, using version 410 does not solve the problem. I want to use this GLSL version to be compatible with older graphics cards; my shader code is covered by 150 core and does not need 410. I am checking shader / program logs after every relevant API call and nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with this call:

```
glUniform1i(uniID, GL_TEXTURE0);
```

The value that needs to be set for a sampler uniform is the index of the texture unit, not the corresponding enum. To sample from texture unit 0, this needs to be:

```
glUniform1i(uniID, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the spot. This is a mistake I made when adding code to the question, rather then the code itself - sorry. The actual code is as you describe (edited).